# Changing dateFormat in ExtJS isn't changing the date submitted

Tags: javascript, mysql, date, extjs, date-format

I'm using Extensible's Calendar http://ext.ensible.com/products/calendar/ but when submitting an event date it's not using the format I'd like for my MySQL backend.

I'm trying to have my Extensible Calendar dates match my mySql date format but I don't know if I'm changing it in the correct spot.

Here is my EventMappings

```
Extensible.calendar.data.EventMappings = {
    EventId:     {name: 'EventId', mapping:'id', type:'int'},
    CalendarId:  {name: 'CalendarId', mapping: 'roomId', type: 'int'},
    Title:       {name: 'Title', mapping: 'description'},
    StartDate:   {name: 'StartDate', mapping: 'start', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'},
    EndDate:     {name: 'EndDate', mapping: 'end', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s'},
    RRule:       {name: 'RRule', mapping: 'rrule'},
    Notes:       {name: 'Notes', mapping: 'notes'},
    Reminder:    {name: 'Reminder', mapping: ''},
    Location:    {name: 'Location', mapping: ''},
    Url:         {name: 'Url', mapping: ''},
    IsAllDay:     {name: 'IsAllDay', mapping: ''},
    User:   {name: 'User', mapping: 'user'},
    Approved:   {name: 'Approved', mapping:'approved', type:'boolean'}
};
```

When I try to post an update to my backend though the date seems to be sent in this format
`Wed Dec 14 2011 01:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)`

I've been banging my head against this for a while and just can't figure it out. I haven't seen anyone else with the same issue so I assuming I'm doing something wrong somewhere.

Any help would be terrific. Thank you.

Comment: Did u try console.log(dateFormat) before submitting the date?

Comment: ya, i noticed the same thing too. you could try using string data type, or overriding the json writer, or adjusting for it on your server

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it by using the *dateParamFormat* property of the relevant calendar view (month view in my case).

```
{
   xtype: 'extensible.calendarpanel',
   // the usual settings (calendar and event store, etc.) 
   ..
   monthViewCfg: {
     ..
     // This is it - a custom date format
     dateParamFormat: 'Y/m/d'
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What does your store / proxy / reader / writer configuration look like?  The issue would not be related to the EventMappings (which map *incoming* data being read from the server) -- it would be related to how the data layer in your app is sending dates in requests.  Also, which OS / browser are you using?